# How to calculate Age on Google Sheets Years / Months?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a formula to calculate age like this manual example:

[image: example]

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two dates expressed as years, months, days (in one column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221147/difference-between-two-dates-expressed-as-years-months-days-in-one-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
=INDEX(IF(D2:D="",,INT(DATEDIF(D2:D,TODAY(),"Y"))&"Y / "& 
                   MOD(DATEDIF(D2:D,TODAY(),"M"),12)&"M"))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`INT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
- [`DATEDIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612)
- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)
- [`MOD`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by the native `DateDif` and `Concatenate` functions:

```
=CONCATENATE(DATEDIF(D3,Now(),"Y"),"y / ",Mod(DATEDIF(D3,Now(),"M"),12),"m")
```

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Morefield , your approach works well, can you help me make it array I tried with `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF` but it doesn't work!

Comment: What do you mean by "Make it an array"? We don't need to do the Concatenation and can put the results into different cells if you would rather use them as separate values (and just hide the columns later)