# Difference between two dates in years days hours minutes format

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, duration

I am trying to find out difference between two days "xx years xx days xx hours xx minutes" format. My start date is in A column and end date is in B. Calculating difference in C column.

I am using `B1-A1` formula in C column and using custom format `"yy" years "dd" days "hh"  hours "mm" minutes"` in C column. It works fine if the start and end years are different. But if it is same, C column reporting incorrect years and days. (showing as 99 years and 30 days).

How to fix it ?

[Sample google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQ5N6PBry-ORMH2GgAALjKDwqlqHZaS19CaJSwGvL5Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `B2 - A2` formula is actually getting the correct result — it is a dateserial value that represents the difference between the two moments in units of *days*.

The problem is with the custom number format you are using. It refers to *calendar* time, while you would need *elapsed* time. Unfortunately, Google Sheets apparently only supports elapsed time in units of hours, minutes and seconds.

If a text string result is OK with you, use this:

`=datedif(A2, B2, "y") & " years " & datedif(A2, B2, "d") - 365 * datedif(A2, B2, "y") & " days " & text(B2 - A2 - int(B2 - A2), "HH ""hours"" mm ""minutes""")`

The formula assumes that all years are 365 days long, which will not be correct when the date span crosses a leap day.

To get the average elapsed time, evaluate `=B2 - A2` for all rows with an array formula, then calculate the average of those results, and finally format the result to your liking, like this:

`=arrayformula( average( if( B2:B + A2:A, B2:B - A2:A, iferror(1/0) ) ) )`

`=datedif(0, G2, "y") & " years " & datedif(0, G2, "d") - 365 * datedif(0, G2, "y") & " days " & text(G2 - 0 - int(G2 - 0), "H ""hours"" m ""minutes""")`

See cells `F2:G2` in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQ5N6PBry-ORMH2GgAALjKDwqlqHZaS19CaJSwGvL5Y/edit?usp=sharing).

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

A bit long, but it works. Would like to try `TEXT` but I have additional conditions for the days since it is tricky due to how sheets calculate the difference when actually they have different days per months. You need to consider the days per months as it is unique.

#### Formula:

```
=datedif(A2, B2, "y")&" years "
&if(day(B2) >= day(A2),
if(index(split(B2, " "), ,2) >= index(split(A2, " "), ,2),
day(B2) - day(A2),
day(B2) - day(A2) - 1),
if(index(split(B2, " "), ,2) >= index(split(A2, " "), ,2),
day(eomonth(B2, -1)) + day(B2) - min(day(A2), day(eomonth(B2, -1))),
day(eomonth(B2, -1)) + day(B2) - min(day(A2), day(eomonth(B2, -1))) -1))&" days "
&hour(B2 - A2)&" hours "
&minute(B2 - A2)&" minutes"
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Formula took care of formatting.
- Days have a very complicated formula due to different days per months. But this should show a more accurate answer
- `index(split(B2, " "), ,2) >= index(split(A2, " "), ,2)` is added on the original [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222439/14606045) to consider later time on start date, reducing the days by 1 if that happens

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222439/14606045

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
 TEXT(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   "0#")&CHOOSE(MATCH(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   {0,1,2})," years ", " year ", " years ")&
 TEXT(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), "0#")&CHOOSE(MATCH(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), {0,1,2})," days ",  " day ",  " days ")&
 TEXT(    TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H"),    "0#")&               CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H")  *1,                   {0,1,2})," hours ", " hour ", " hours ")&
 TEXT(INT(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")), "0#")&               CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")*1,                   {0,1,2})," minutes"," minute"," minutes"),
 "\b0 (year(s)|day(s)|hour(s)|minute(s))", ))))
```

- works with leap years
- works with singular
- works with plural
- works with arrays
- works with seconds
- works with dates only
- works with time only
- works with less than a day
- works with blank rows
- excludes all null values

[image]

---

to remove only leading null values:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
 TEXT(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   {0,1,2})," years ", " year ", " years ")&
 TEXT(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), {0,1,2})," days ",  " day ",  " days ")&
 TEXT(    TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H"),                   "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H")  *1,                   {0,1,2})," hours ", " hour ", " hours ")&
 TEXT(INT(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")),                "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")*1,                   {0,1,2})," minutes"," minute"," minutes"),
 "^\b(?:00 years )?(?:00 days )?(?:00 hours )?(?:00 minutes)?", ))))
```

[image]

---

to `NOT` remove any null values:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(
 TEXT(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   {0,1,2})," years ", " year ", " years ")&
 TEXT(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), {0,1,2})," days ",  " day ",  " days ")&
 TEXT(    TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H"),                   "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H")  *1,                   {0,1,2})," hours ", " hour ", " hours ")&
 TEXT(INT(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")),                "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")*1,                   {0,1,2})," minutes"," minute"," minutes"),
 "^\b00 years 00 days 00 hours 00 minutes", )))
```

[image]

---

to have it aligned with Mars, Jupiter and Saturn:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 TEXT(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),    "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(                DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "Y"),   {0,1,2})," years ", " year  ", " years ")&
 TEXT(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), "000")&CHOOSE(MATCH(IF(B2:B-A2:A<1,,DATEDIF(A2:A, B2:B, "YD")), {0,1,2})," days ",  " day  ",  " days ")&
 TEXT(    TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H"),                    "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "H")  *1,                   {0,1,2})," hours ", " hour  ", " hours ")&
 TEXT(INT(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")),                 "00")&CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXT(B2:B-A2:A, "M.S")*1,                   {0,1,2})," minutes"," minute "," minutes"),
 "^\b00 years 000 days 00 hours 00 minutes", ), "(0)(\d{2})", " $2")))
```

[image]

---

---

### update:

for average use either:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(IF(B2:B+A2:A, B2:B-A2:A, )))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(IFERROR(1/(1/(B2:B-A2:A)))))
```

depends on the sensitivity you need

Comment: > Thanks for the explanation. What will be the better option to identify average. I was able to use average function earlier, but now  its not working. may be in a column convert them into minutes and average it then change back to year-day-hr-mn format ?

Comment: @acr answer updated for average

Answer (score 0):

Put if condition if both values are same then it should be otherwise do subtract

```
=IF(A1=B1,"0",B1-A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the GS considers the zero date to be the first day of its calendar, i.e. 1899-12-30. You can get a correct result with following formula:

```
       =TEXT(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"Y"),"00 \y\ear\s ") & 
         TEXT(TRUNC(EDATE(B2,-12*(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"Y")))-A2), "00 \da\y\s ") & 
         TEXT(ABS((B2-TRUNC(B2,0))-(A2-TRUNC(A2,0))+1),"hh \hour\s mm \minut\e\s")
```

or using arrayformula:

```
    =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),
     TEXT(DATEDIF(A2:A,B2:B,"Y"),"00 \y\ear\s ") & 
     TEXT(TRUNC(EDATE(B2:B,-12*(DATEDIF(A2:A,B2:B,"Y")))-A2:A), "00 \da\y\s ") & 
     TEXT(ABS((B2:B-TRUNC(B2:B,0))-(A2:A-TRUNC(A2:A,0))+1),"hh \hour\s mm \minut\e\s"),))
```

The formula takes into account the leap years and calculates elapsed days.

[image]

Comment: Somehow it results into an unexpected difference of 1 day. Try sample `14-12-2021  00:00` and `15-12-2021  00:00`.

Comment: @NaziA Yes, you're right, the correct formula got a lot more complicated.

Comment: mostly due to the different days per month i believe. when including the calculation of days per month, it will get accurate as what Tom Sharpe's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222439/14606045). Adjusted it in my answer to include the time difference especially when start time is greater than end time in terms of individual time values.